# jQuery determine if a audio is finished playing and trigger function after that

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have generated audio links from a javascript file and I triggered audio play using jQuery. I want to trigger a function when audio is finished.

Here's my HTML.

```
<div id="audio-holder" class="text-center">

</div>
```

Dynamically creating element from javascript objects:

```
$.each( page15, function( key, value ) {
    $("#audio-holder").append(
          "<span class='word' data-audio-path='"+value.audio+"'>"+value.word+"</span>"
    )});
```

Here's player code:

```
$( ".word" ).each(function(index) {
     $(this).on("click", function(){
         var audioSrc = $(this).attr("data-audio-path");
         var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
         audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioSrc);
         audioElement.play();

         // Here goes custom function
     });
});
```

Another problem is if I click one word its playing one audio and in the meantime if I click another audio plays along with previous audio. How can I stop previous audio when new audio starts.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `ended` event and then do your stuff.

```js
yourAudio.addEventListener("ended", function(){
     yourAudio.currentTime = 0;
     console.log("ended");
});
```

Comment: What about getting rid of playing multiple audio once?

Comment: The simplest way is to loop through all the audio and check their status and stop them.

Comment: But all these are dynamic/virtual DOM. I tried to access them, but couldn't

Comment: If you could share a codesandbox link of your issue then may be it would easier for all to understand the exact issue